# Getting I/O error on HTTP POST request after sometime

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for end point : `http://IP/service/api/api_name`

using restTemplate.postForEntity(url, json, TokenResponse.class) to post information.

So basically I am calling a HTTP POST on above url on an application installed on IIS server.

After sometime I starts getting I/O error, while I am able to post through postman.
What could be the cause this to happen.

Is my service has some issue or the service which I am requesting is unable to handle connection pool?

Comment: Not closing resources ?

Comment: Hi @Atiq can you please add more code on your `restTemplate` implementation? And through Postman you never encountered any issue?